# 'War is hell' in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Some ideas I have come up with are:-
bellum est infandum  war is an abomination
inmite est bellum war is pitiless
res cruenta et infanda est Mars War is a blood-soaked atrocity
Mars furit infandus War blasphemously rages out of control.
Marte nulla pestis saevior est no instrument of destruction is more savage than war.

For 'infandus' I suppose 'nefandus' could be substituted, the difference apparently being that nefandus implies the idea of a crime which nefandus does not necessarily always do, as 'arma nefanda' = "war so base that it is not to be spoken of without horror'.
'Caesar' In De Bello Hispaniensi writes of the barbarians 'nefandum crudelissimumque facinus aunt adgressi'.

Comment: Any particular cultural milieu you have in mind?  I rather suspect this translates quite differently in a Christian vs a pagan context, for example.

Comment: Only CL equivalent. Something concise and graphic, like atrocissimum est bellum.

Comment: Probably the best Latin would be bellum est Gehenna, suggested to me by a friend, Emeritus Professor Diggle.
The concept of hell, in our sense of the word, is alien to  the Classical world.